# Finding Load time of website using Javascript

Tags: javascript, page-load-time

I want to find the load time of a locally hosted website. Is this way efficient? How can I display the time in a dialogue box?

```js
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
             var loadTime = window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventEnd- window.performance.timing.navigationStart;
        </script>
        </head>
        
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
          window.onload = function () {
    var loadTime = ((window.performance.timing.domComplete- window.performance.timing.navigationStart)/1000)+" sec.";
    console.log('Page load time is '+ loadTime);
}
        </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use your browser developer tools for this? It's much easier to profile everything that way

Comment: Do you mean from the network tab pressing F12? I could not get what was happening there so I wanted the easy way to read the load time.

Comment: Yes, and it's far easier to see the total time plus the per resource time that way. Look for the OnDomContentLoaded number if your browser supports it for the effective total render

Comment: Does the developer tool give accurate load time?

Comment: Yes, they do. In all modern browsers

Answer (score 1):

@Samrat Shrestha  This snippet work for you

```
<doctype html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                 console.log("Time until DOMready: ",window.performance.timing.loadEventEnd-window.performance.timing.navigationStart);
             });
        </script>
        <!-- do all the stuff you need to do -->
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

The ready event occurs after the HTML document has been loaded.
window.onload fires when the entire page loads (images, styles, etc.)

[window.onload vs $(document).ready()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation_timing_API#Examples

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceTiming/loadEventEnd